# How do I use least and less?

Tags: word-usage

How do I use **least** and **less**? for example, can I say this? This is a novel I'm writing and the character who says this phrase is supposed to be ignorant and immature.

> Come on, hop on my back and try to make this **the least** silly possible, I don't want the girls to see this.

or

> Come on, hop on my back and try to make this **the less** silly possible,  I don't want the girls to see this.

or

> Come on, hop on my back and try to make this **as less as** silly possible,  I don't want the girls to see this.

Answer (score 3):

A very common and idiomatic way of using 'possible' in a sentence is to use the construction:

> as **X** as possible.

where X can be any number of adjectives.

> as **little** as possible.
>
> as **much** as possible.

So, I think, in quoted speech, where informal grammar is acceptable, you could 'quote' the character saying something that English speakers will often do - which is (sort of) making words up on the fly where they are needed.

> Come on, hop on my back and try to make this as **un-silly** as possible, I don't want the girls to see this.

'Un-silly' is a single word adjective which might well be used by someone, although it is not in a dictionary. Just adding 'un' reverses the meaning of the word. 'Un' can be used with other adjectives which [cough] might be used here.

Or avoid the negation, and say it this way:

> Come on, hop on my back and try to make this as **sensible** as possible.

Or reword to avoid the whole problem

> Come on, hop on my back, and try not to make it look dumb/stupid/embarassing.

Of your three choices, the first one is the closest to being acceptable, but I would suggest none of them sound entirely natural, and the second two are ungrammatical.